# spark structure streaming with efs is causing delay in job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Im using Spark Structure streaming 2.4.4. Im using Spark with kubernetes. But when i enable local checkpointing in some /tmp/ folder, jobs finishes in 7-8s. If EFS is mounted and checkpointing location is used on that then jobs are taking more than 5 mins and its quite unstable.

Please find the screenshot from spark sql tab.
[image]

Comment: Since it's all about listing and writing files to the checkpoint location, I'd check out the time it takes to do a file listing or creating small files. I'm sure that's the root cause of the issues.

Comment: @jacek how can I check the same? On mounted system if I do it works well. Would like to see from spark checkpointing logs

Comment: No idea. I'd simply log in to the node that's slow and use command line to `mkdir`, `ls`, and such. I'm not sure if that's even possible, but I'd bypass Spark to see how the filesystem behaves in general.